# Photoluminescence Spectra of Solids

Tags: spectroscopy, reference-request, uv-vis-spectroscopy, semiconductors

What information can we gain with the photoluminescence spectra of solids?  The bandgap can be determined for example, but are there any other useful properties we can learn?  I care about this in the context of semiconductors but other answers are also appreciated.

Comment: Bandgap, defect states and dynamics, excitons, carrier dynamics, ...

Comment: Can you provide a source for some of this?  I am finding it hard to get a good source, even knowing roughly what I expect to find out.

Comment: Pankove's classic Optical Processes in Semiconductors is a good starting point.